# Ocultar el jsessionid del navegador

Tags: java, jsp, http

Tengo una aplicación en java y al ejecutarla me sale en la url algo como esto

> `http://127.0.0.1:8080/Login.do;jsessionid=111111111`

Quisiera evitar que sea visible para el usuario esta variable

Answer (score 0):

creo que estás enviando el resultado del formulario de login mediante GET, GET siempre te mostrará lo que envía en la URL, para evitarlo puedes enviar la información usando POST o usando una de estas variantes:

1. desde el servlet:

```
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("url.jsp"));
```

2. desde javaScript

```
document.location.href = document.location.href;
```